# How do I check file timestamp attributes in Perl 6?

Tags: perl, timestamp, raku

In Perl 5, you can use [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) to get the accessed, modified, and changed timestamps of files.

For example:

```
my $filename = "sample.txt";
my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
       $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks)
           = stat($filename)

print "File '$filename' was last accessed $atime seconds since the epoch.\n";
```

Which results in:

```
File 'sample.txt' was last accessed 1431707004 seconds since the epoch.
```

How do you check file time stamps in Perl 6?

Answer (score 4):

The [file test operators from Perl 5](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html), in Perl 6 are methods (e.g.  `.modified`, `.accessed` and `.changed`) from the [`IO::FileTestable` role](http://doc.perl6.org/type/IO::FileTestable).

For example:

```
my $filename = "sample.txt";
my $seconds_since_epoch = $filename.IO.accessed;
my $readable_timestamp  = DateTime.new($filename.IO.accessed);

say "File '$filename' was last accessed at '$readable_timestamp', which is {$seconds_since_epoch.Num} seconds since the epoch";
```

in my case, gave:

```
File 'sample.txt' was last accessed at '2015-05-15T16:22:49Z', which is 1431707004 seconds since the epoch
```